# Is it possible to enable push notification developed using MobileFirst SDK7.1 can run of MobileFirst Server V8.0?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

We have app developed using MF SDK7.1 where the app supporting Push notification. Now we have only MobileFirst Server8.0. I'm seeing most of the APIs are not supporting in the MF server 8. So is there any way i can use Push notification behaviour devloped in 7.1 work on MobileFirst server 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

MFP 7.1 Client SDK is not compatible with MFP 8.0 Server. Hence this is not possible.

Consider migrating your client application from 7.1 to 8.0 version.

For more details on 7.x to 8.0 migration : [check here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migrating-client-applications/)